# YA book with a boy who is connected to a deer

Tags: identification-request

A YA book I read in the 90s followed the love triangle of the main character. He was a boy who developed a connection with a deer he sees in the wilderness near his home. The love triangle also included the daughter of the mayor (?) who hunted and was adept with guns, and the weird girl who understands him and his connection to the deer more.

Comment: Similar stories that are *not* what you're looking for, with boy-deer bonds but no love triangles: [*The Yearling* by Marjorie Kinnan Rawlings](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/159582.The_Yearling), [*A Boy and a Deer* by Darrell A Rolerson](https://www.amazon.com/Boy-Deer-Darrell-Rolerson/dp/0396071724). If we can find any sort of "similar books" list for these, it might include the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

"A Fabulous Creature" by Zilpha Keatley Snyder could be a possibility.

Description from [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/127125.A_Fabulous_Creature):

> James Fielding is ready to dive into his plan for the summer - the Don
> Juan Project, guaranteed to transform him into a successful ladies'
> man. But his parents have decided to spend the summer at an isolated
> resort in the Sierra Nevadas, and James is pretty sure he won't even
> catch a glimpse of a girl.
>
> But to his surprise, he meets two girls: the pretty and ruthless Diane
> Jarrett, and Griffin Donahue, a free spirit more at home in the forest
> than the real world. The summer holds even more wonder when James
> discovers a magnificent stag in a hidden valley. But will sharing this
> fabulous secret destroy something he has come to cherish?